# Extract column from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

How can I extract a column as pandas df from a following pandas df containing dictionary: (I need all values of 'name' with the index)

```
nutrients_df
Out[63]: 
                                          nutrients
0     [{'code': '203cp1252', 'name': 'Proteincp1252'...
1     [{'code': '203cp1252', 'name': 'Proteincp1252'...
2     [{'code': '203cp1252', 'name': 'Proteincp1252'...
3     [{'code': '203cp1252', 'name': 'Proteincp1252'...
4     [{'code': '203cp1252', 'name': 'Proteincp1252'...
5     [{'code': '203cp1252', 'name': 'Proteincp1252'...
6     [{'code': '203cp1252', 'name': 'Proteincp1252'...
```

"nutrients_df" is defined as pandas df from json database as follows:

```
nutrient_name=[]
for index, row in data_df.iterrows():
    nutrients1 = row['nutrients']
    nutrients.append(nutrients1)    
    nutrients_df = pd.DataFrame({'nutrients': nutrients})
```

Comment: is `nutrients` a list containing dictionary objects? Can you show a full (non-truncated) example of a value from that column?

Comment: Thank you for the help! It is a column of json database. I defined nutrients_df as follows: nutrient_name=[]                                                 for index, row in data_df.iterrows():                                                                        
    nutrients1 = row['nutrients']
    nutrients.append(nutrients1)    
    nutrients_df = pd.DataFrame({'nutrients': nutrients})

Comment: make sure you [edit] your question to add any additional information - comments don't work well for that :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what data type is present in your `df.nutrients` series. Below are a couple of examples of how you might extract `name` from within a dictionary-like object.

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

# If your columns are genuine dictionaries
df = pd.DataFrame([[{'code': '203cp1252', 'name': 'Proteincp1252'}],
                   [{'code': '203cp1252', 'name': 'Proteincp1253'}],
                   [{'code': '203cp1252', 'name': 'Proteincp1254'}]],
                  columns=['nutrients'])

df['name'] = df['nutrients'].apply(lambda x: x['name'])

# If your column is a string
df = pd.DataFrame([["{'code': '203cp1252', 'name': 'Proteincp1252'}"],
                   ["{'code': '203cp1252', 'name': 'Proteincp1253'}"],
                   ["{'code': '203cp1252', 'name': 'Proteincp1254'}"]],
                  columns=['nutrients'])

df['name'] = df['nutrients'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x)['name'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The thing is that I tried similar specification, but it did not work. The problem is that I converted json database to pandas df and the way it looks is like you have "nutrients" column and inside it you have a dictionary as specified above.

Comment: that's great, feel free to accept (tick on left) if it solved your problem.

Comment: the thing is that it keeps giving the following error - "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". Is there is a way to correct it?

Comment: once I run 10th line of code. However, when I run " If your column is a string" I get the following error - "  raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string:"

Comment: Sorry, I would need to see the full traceback and the exact line!

Comment: I applied your code to my df. An then I get the following error:                                          
df = pd.DataFrame(data_df, columns=['nutrients'])    
df['name'] = df['nutrients'].apply(lambda x: x['name'])
df['name'] = df['nutrients'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x)['name'])

Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: File "<ipython-input-24-8aec8defb5b4>", line 2, in <module>
    df['name'] = df['nutrients'].apply(lambda x: x['name'])

  File "C:\Users\Alberto\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2355, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

  File "pandas\_libs\src\inference.pyx", line 1574, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer (pandas\_libs\lib.c:66645)

  File "<ipython-input-24-8aec8defb5b4>", line 2, in <lambda>
    df['name'] = df['nutrients'].apply(lambda x: x['name'])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str